# Firebase Rest API for android app performance results

Tags: firebase, firebase-performance

As we all know that App performance monitoring has been provided by Firebase. I have integrated my app with the same and got results at Firebase console. I would like to get the results through Rest API provided by Firebase or some other way. Please let me know if any API provided by the Firebase for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's currently no REST API for Firebase Performance Monitoring.  Please file a [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) if you would like to see that.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Do you know any work around to achieve this? It will be better if  the results can be mailed from the console on nightly basis.

Comment: I'm with the Firebase team.  If there was a way to do this I'd let you know.  :-)  Please file a feature request to help the team understand what you would like to see.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: One more question. Can I fetch the performance data through database ?

Comment: No, there's currently no forms of data export.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. So I am blocked tottally... :(